# Xcode5.0 crash every time when i open it. Is there any solution?

Tags: xcode

I download the xcode 5.0 and ios 7 beta.But xcode 5.0 crash everytime when i open it. Is there any solution? 
I use MBP 2012. Mac os is 10.8.4.

Comment: It's still in beta. (However, I run it happily, Mac OS 10.9)